# Trying to run npm commands from Python file...runs the first npm command but causes error for the next npm command. Running this is VS Code terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, npm

```
    #import necesscary libraries
    from git import Repo
    import os
    import shutil
    
    git_dir = "https://github.com/devias-io/material-kit-react.git" #git directory
    local_dir = "C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\Internship\\git_clone\\data\\" #local 
    directory to clone the file with the data folder
    practice_dir = "C:\\Users\\A\\Desktop\\Internship\\internship-forms-trial\\" 
    #practice directory
    
    
    shutil.rmtree(local_dir) #removes the data folder if one exists --cloning cannot take 
    place in a folder that has files
    os.makedirs(local_dir) #makes a data folder to clone the data into
    
    clone = Repo.clone_from(git_dir, local_dir ) #cloning process
    
    
    change_dir = os.chdir(local_dir) #changing directory to the local directory
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    print("Current directory: ", current_dir)
    
    npm_install = os.system('cmd /k "npm i"') #npm install command to install modules
    npm_build = os.system('cmd /k "npm run build"' ) #npm build command to build the app
    serve = os.system('cmd/k "serve -s build"' ) #serve to deploy onto static server
    open_website = os.system('cmd/k "start chrome http://localhost:3000"') #opens up the 
    webapp on local host
    
    
    
    ## for the github file above instead of npm_build use "npm run dev" 
     ##https://github.com/devias-io/material-kit-react or uncomment and use the code below. 
    ##npm_dev = os.system('cmd /k "npm run dev"' )
```

The error I get is the one below:

```
    C:\Users\A\Desktop\Internship\git_clone\data>npm_dev = 
    os.system('cmd /k "npm 
    run dev"' )
    'npm_dev' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

This code works for the first npm command - npm_install but when I try to run the npm_dev command it fails and produces me the error above.

Comment: You probably wanted to type `npm_dev = os.system('cmd /k "npm run dev"' )` into a python terminal session to test? Because as of now you are trying to execute this inside powershell terminal which as you can see cannot recognize `npm_dev` command.

Comment: Is it possible to keep the same terminal when running all the commands. On the right of my terminal. It says it is Python but it dosen't work. Can you clarify this please?

Comment: Everytime I delete my current python terminal and add a new one it works. Why is that? Is it not possible to keep using the same terminal after the command?

Comment: To use launch Python in terminal just type `python` and click Enter. You should see that each line starts with `>>>` that's how you can confirm it launched it correctly.